# Append to the beginning of an Array

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to append a string to the beginning of an existing array.

```
char array[50] = {5,A,0,1,0,0,1,1};
char firstElement[] = {"F"};
char secondElement[] = {"s", "S"};
```

I understand that we can use memcpy or strcat to append to an array. But I want to append to the beginning of my existing array. Can you please tell me how?

Comment: The third line of your code block will generate compiler error. You're trying to pack two char* in a char array.

Comment: Minor vocabulary tweak: *append* is at the end, *prepend* at the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

Not without copying the elements - any reason not use a c++ std::vector?

```
std::vector<char> array;
array.push_back(5); // adds to end
array.push_back(A);

// insert a new array at beginning
char myarray [] = { 1,2,3 };
array.insert (array.begin(), myarray, myarray+3);
```

If you need to insert things at the front a std::deque is more efficient but otherwise is identical to a vector

```
std::deque<char> array;
array.push_back(5); // adds to end
array.push_back(A);
array.push_front(4); // inserts at front
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use it? Coz I am new to C++. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The very simplest way to do this is to use a `std::string` rather than battling with character arrays:

```
std::string s = ", world!";
s = "Hello" + s;
```

I've taken a bit of a leap in assuming that you are really working with strings. If it really is an array of characters that you want, then perhaps use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1):

the only thing i see you can do is to shift your array to the right and write the first element at the beginning.

```
for (int i = 48 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    array[i+1] = array[i];
}
array[0] = firstElement[0];
```

the total lenght of your string have to be less than 50, otherwise, you will lose the extra characters

you can also use a list. you will be able to append in the beginning without rewriting the chars

Comment: The total length is definetely >176. What can I do in that case?

Comment: I said 50 because you declare `int array[50]`. but if you declare an array with the riht lenght 177 or another number, there will be no problem. if the size is `n`, use this line : `for (int i = n-2 ; i >= 0 ; i--)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes in your code:

```
char array[50] = {5,A,0,1,0,0,1,1};
```

All your values (excluding A, which I guess is a variable) are not chars (tecnically, they could be casted, but this is not correct).

```
char firstElement[] = {"F"};
char secondElement[] = {"s", "S"};
```

This two arrays are also incorrect, because "F", "s" and "S" are not chars, but strings (or char*).

Despite this, I think the best way to solve your problems is to use the `std:String` and the function `append`:

```
string str1 ="Frist string";
string str2 ="Second string";
str1.append(str2);
```

No `memcpy` nor `strcat` needed, you're using C++, not C, take advantage of it!

Comment: It's not uncommon to use `char` or `unsigned char` to store a single byte, since C doesn't have a `byte` data type.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about inserting at the beginning of an Array in C. It's the same as inserting at any place, and it's inefficient, as it involves shifting the entire array:

- Shift your entire array to the right using

  ```
  memcpy(array + 3 * sizeof(char), array, 8 * sizeof(char));
  ```
- Copy the new elements at their place:

  ```
  memcpy(array, firstElement, sizeof(firstElement));
  memcpy(array + sizeof(firstElement), secondElement, sizeof(secondElement));
  ```

Also, you should correct your arrays declarations to be arrays of char by using single quotes.

As other pointed, you should use `std::string` if you write your program in C++.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done without using `memcpy` or similar to move the elements in memory. The array is a continguous piece of memory, and you have filled the start of that memory, therefore there is no space at the begining to append any elements. You need to move the current elements away from the start of the array and then you can insert elements at the start. Otherwise consider using `std::vector<T>`, which allows you to insert elements at arbitrary locations and takes care of moving the current elements around

Answer (score 0):

In your code the following declarations won't compile:

`A` is constant and undeclared

```
char arr[50] = {5,A,0,1,0,0,1,1};
```

you want a character `'F'`, when you say, `"F"` it represents a string literal. Note that `'\0'` null character is implicitly added when you initialize char array.

```
char firstElement[] = {"F"};
```

same as above, in this case you have too many intializers, therefore you should have `'s' and 'S'`

```
char secondElement[] = {"s", "S"};
```

To simplify the copy, C++ provides you [std::string](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=std%20string&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/&ei=DBu6TqnrHMWxrAeHxd20Bg&usg=AFQjCNHYSO65lBUum_PPFu0nJcwzb0EW9w) which can be used to append two strings at any end.

```
std::string first = "F";
std::string second = "sS";
second.append(first); 
first.append(second); // OR
```