# In C, is array initialization with only one element treated specially?

Tags: c, arrays

While reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060931/append-to-the-beginning-of-an-array/8061034#8061034) I wanted to test the input in GCC to see what errors would be output. To my surprise the following line:

```
char array[] = {"s"};
```

compiles without error or warning, resulting in an array of size 2 containing `"s\0"`. I would have expected a compiler error because the right side of the expression  is of type `char*[]`.

Is an array initialization with only one element not treated as an array in this case, and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char array[] = {"s"};
```

is same as:

```
char array[] = "s";
```

Here `{ }` are optional in this case because "s" is string literal.

Or,

```
char array[] = {'s', '\0'};
```

In this case, `{ }` are necessary to initialize the array.

Comment: in particular in C you can actually initialize scalars using { } ... I wonder however if it has any impact on alignment. Nope.. no impact on alignment :)

Comment: OK. So I have to consider the whole expression in this case, and not only the left side? `{"s"}` is definitely not the same as `"s"`, for instance `char array *[] = {"s"};` is valid but `char array *[] = "s";` is not.

Comment: @Antoine: When you say, `char array*[]` you're declaring an array of pointers, in that particular case you'll have to provide an initializer list.

Comment: OK, so this answer the question in my comment: The meaning of the right side of the initialization expression depends on the type of the left side, which sounds strange.

Comment: @cpx: `char array*[]` is not a legal declaration.

Comment: ops, sorry I meant to say `char *array[]`.

Comment: Yes I meant that too :) `char* array []`. Thanks dreamlax.

Answer (score -10):

a correctly initialized string is :

```
char array[] = "something";
```

its a 10 char array.

but if you write  :

```
`char* array = "something";`
```

`it is a different object, you will not be able to modify the content of array.

and :

```
char* array[]
```

is not a string.

it is an array of char pointers (char*). you need to allocate the memory for each char*

exp :

```
char* array[3];
array[0] = malloc (10*sizeof(char));
strcpy(array[0] , "hello");
```

but, to have an array of char*, you can not do directly :

```
char* array[3];
array[0] = "hello";
```

neither :

```
char* array[] = {"first","second","other one","last"};
```

with this init, the strings can not be modified.

for people saying what i write is totaly wrong, do you know that a char* needs a memory allocation ?

so why the  -6 or more ?