# Braces around string literal in char array declaration valid? (e.g. char s[] = {"Hello World"})

Tags: c++, c, string, arrays, array-initialization

By accident I found that the line `char s[] = {"Hello World"};` is properly compiled and seems to be treated the same as `char s[] = "Hello World";`. Isn't the first (`{"Hello World"}`) an array containing one element that is an array of char, so the declaration for s should read `char *s[]`? In fact if I change it to `char *s[] = {"Hello World"};` the compiler accepts it as well, as expected.

Searching for an answer, the only place I found which mentioned this is [this one](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/aryin.htm) but there is no citing of the standard.

So my question is, why the line `char s[] = {"Hello World"};` is compiled although the left side is of type `array of char` and the right side is of type `array of array of char`?

Following is a working program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    char s[] = {"Hello World"};
    printf("%s", s); // Same output if line above is char s[] = "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any clarifications.

P.S. My compiler is gcc-4.3.4.

Comment: I posted a similar question a few months ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061346/in-c-is-array-initialization-with-only-one-element-treated-specially

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's allowed because the standard says so: C99 section 6.7.8, §14:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally
>   enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the
>   terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
>   elements of the array.

What this means is that both

```
char s[] = { "Hello World" };
```

and

```
char s[] = "Hello World";
```

are nothing more than syntactic sugar for

```
char s[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', 0 };
```

On a related note (same section, §11), C also allows braces around scalar initializers like

```
int foo = { 42 };
```

which, incidentally, fits nicely with the syntax for compound literals

```
(int){ 42 }
```

Comment: Nearly identical text is in C++2003, clause 8.5.2.

Comment: The ability to use the superfluous braces around initializers for scalar objects also supports the "universal zero initializer" idiom in C language, where the `= { 0 }` can be used to initialize an object of virtually *any* type with zeroes.

Comment: In general, braces simply group all statements contained within them into a single, bigger, statement.  This is why you don't need `{ }` for one line `if` branches (or while, etc).  The compiler simply looks for the _next statement_ after the `if` and executes it conditionally.  So, if you want two statments, just make them appear as one by surrounding them in curlies.

Comment: Similar rules apply to `( )` and commas.  `a = (x = 1, y = 2, z = 3);` will execute all the inner terms and return x as it's value, so a = 1  will be the result.  However, this is not the same as `{x = 1, y = 2, z = 3}` which simply executes the three statements.  In both cases, however, `x, y, z` end up as 1, 2, and 3, respectively.

Comment: @DavidCowden: That is incorrect. `a = (x = 1, y = 2, z = 3);` will set `a` to `3`, not `1`.

Comment: @DavidCowden: That's just comma expression.

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, sorry it was late (=

Comment: @David Cowden: The usage of `{}` in the context of initialization has absolutely no relation to their usage in the compound statement syntax.

Comment: `It's allowed because the standard says so` - most used sentence in SO

Answer (score 22):

The braces are optional, and the expression is equivalent to just an array of char.

You can also write this:

```
 int a = {100}; //ok
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/z0psd

In fact, `C++11` generalizes this very syntax, to initialize non-arrays as well as arrays, uniformly. So in `C++11`, you can have these:

```
int a{}; //a is initialized to zero, and it is NOT an array

int b[]{1,2,3,4}; //b is an array of size 4 containing elements 1,2,3,4

int c[10]{}; //all 10 elements are initialized to zero

int *d{}; //pointer initialized to nullptr

std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5}; //vector is initialized uniformly as well.
```

Answer (score 4):

Any variable in (`int`, `char`, etc.) is just an array of length 1.

```
char s = {0};
```

works as well.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but I think this is not an array of arrays of chars, but a block contains an array of chars. `int a = {1};` may work as well.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] In fact if I change it to
>   char *s[] = {"Hello World"}; the compiler accepts it as well, as
>   expected

The compiler accepets it,because actually, you're making an array 2D of undefined size elements,where you stored one element only,the `"Hello World"` string. Something like this:

```
char* s[] = {"Hello world", "foo", "baa" ...};
```

You can't omit the `bracets` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is allowed by the C++ standard as well, Citation:

> [[dcl.init.string] §1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.string#1)
>
> An array of narrow character type ([basic.fundamental]), char16_t array, char32_t array, or wchar_t array can be initialized by a narrow string literal, char16_t string literal, char32_t string literal, or wide string literal, respectively, **or** by an appropriately-typed string literal **enclosed in braces** ([lex.string]). [snip]