# Can a vector<string *> be initialized directly without new?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm in the process of learning C++/general programming and sometimes experiment with C++11 features while doing exercises written for the older standard.

This exercise involves a vector of pointers to strings.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using std::string ;
    using std::vector ;
    using std::cout ;
    using std::endl ;

    vector<string *> v = {new string("Hello") , new string("World")} ;
    for (string * x : v) {
        cout << *x << " " ;
        delete x ;
    }
    cout << endl ;
}
```

I had a little difficulty figuring how to use the initialization list with this vector, but this seems to work.

This version also works:

```
    //...
    string s1 = "Hello" ;
    string s2 = "World" ;
    vector<string *> v = {&s1 , &s2} ;
    for (string * x : v)
        cout << *x << " " ;
    //...
```

It looks cleaner, and from what I've learned so far it seems like the better solution.

But I find myself wondering: is there some other way to initialize the vector without creating the strings ahead of time or having to use delete? What I read suggests the {} list should be usable universally.

And for what it's worth, this gives a rather catastrophic error:

```
vector<string *> v = {"Hello" , "World"} ;
```

Answer (score 12):

Why do you use `std::string*` in the first place?  Do you have any reason for that? I don't think so.

Use this:

```
std::vector<std::string> v{"Hello" , "World"};
```

Now, you don't need to use `new`. Such classes are designed precisely because you could avoid using `new` yourself.

Also note that there is no `'='` between `'v'` and `'{'` in the initialization above. This initialization is called *uniform initialization* introduced by C++11. [More examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10147335/415784).

Comment: It does seem arbitrary, but the exercise goes on to use the arrow operator, so it probably uses pointers just for the sake of that. Then, once I tried to use the initialization list instead of push_back(), I ran into this, and now I'm mostly curious if there's another way, not really related to the original problem.

Comment: @Enra: You're using a bad example to learn arrow operator. Why don't you implement some class yourself, and explore how to use `->` along with many other things, which you will learn in the process.

Comment: doesn't even work on apple clang 4.2, i'm a little disappointed.

Answer (score 3):

> But I find myself wondering: is there some other way to initialize the vector without creating the strings ahead of time or having to use delete?

No, to store pointers to *something*, you have to have this something stored somewhere else. Otherwise there will be no place for the pointer to point to.

That it feels odd is probably because this *is* an unusual way to store strings. If it wasn't an (artificial) exercise, you could be using a `std::vector<std::string>>`  and get rid of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Like Nawaz said, why bother using pointers to strings? Just for the sake of using the -> operator? Make a class that has a few private variables and return them using references. That's a better example of when to use the arrow operator.