# what is the differences for a value declared in a list surrounding by a curly bracket and no curly bracket

Tags: c, initialization, string-literals, list-initialization

I'm a beginner in C programming and I can't figure out what the difference is between these two expressions (with and without curly brackets) as follows.

```
char s1[] = {"The course of true love never did run smooth"};
char s1[] = "The course of true love never did run smooth";
```

I try to test by using

```
printf("%c", s1[0]), and 
printf("%s", s1)
```

Both giving me same answer.

Comment: There is no difference in the initialization of the array, both ar equivalent.

Comment: seems like a dupe of [Braces around string literal in char array declaration valid? (e.g. char s\[\] = {"Hello World"})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147264/braces-around-string-literal-in-char-array-declaration-valid-e-g-char-s)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, the braces are optional.

From the standard 6.7.9/14:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.

Comment: As for the rationale why braces are optionally allowed, I suspect it is because braces can in some cases make it easier to do generic programming with various different initializer lists using macros. I don't have any source for that though.

Answer (score 1):

In fact when a character array is initialized by a string literal like for example

```
char s[] = "Hello";
```

then such an initialization is equivalent to the following

```
char s[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

That is elements of the string literal form an initializer list.

So you may initialize an array like

```
char s[] = "Hello";
```

or like

```
char s[] = { "Hello" };
```

to show that elements of the literal form an initializer list.

Pay attention also to that you may initialize scalar objects also like for example

```
int x = 10;
```

or

```
int x = { 10 };
```